# Quarkus @QuarkusTest vs @QuarkusIntegrationTest

Tags: testing, quarkus

Apologies if it has been answered before, but I can't seem to find a good answer.

What is the context of how `@QuarkusTest` runs versus `QuarkusIntegrationTest`?

So far, all I got is the integration test runs against a packaged form of the app (`.jar`, native compilation), whereas the plain `@QuarkusTest` doesn't? But this does not leave much explanation, and apologies if this comes from a lack of understanding in test runtimes.

To start a test instance of Quarkus (via `@QuarkusTest`), does it not compile and package into a jar? Makes sense to not I suppose, and just test against running compiled classes but I would rather get the real answer than assuming.

https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#native-executable-testing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Besides the difference you mention, there's another crucial difference between `@QuarkusTest` and `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`. With `@QuarkusTest`, the test runs in the same process as the tested application, so you can inject the application's beans into the test instance etc., while with `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`, the tested application runs in an external process, so you can only interact with it over network.